# Proving The Range Of Continuous Functions

Tags: calculus

Consider a continuous function $f(x)R:\to R$ satisfying the property $$|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y|$$, then prove that the range of the function $f(x)$ is $R$
$$$$As it is given that $$|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y|$$ so for all $x \neq y$ we have $|x-y|>0$ and hence $$|f(x)-f(y)| \geq |x-y| > 0$$. So for all $x \neq y$ we have $f(x) \neq f(y)$, so $f(x)$ is a one - one function and as it is continuous so it is a monotonic function. Let us assume without the loss of generality that it is increasing so for all $x>y$ we have $f(x) \geq f(y)$. So from the given inequality we get for all $x>0$ we have $$f(x)-f(0) \geq x$$ and for all $x<0$ we have $$f(0)-f(x) \geq -x => f(x)-f(0) \leq x$$. Now for any $M$ if $M-f(0)>0$ then for $x>M-f(0)$ we have $$f(x)-f(0) \geq x>M-f(0) => f(x)>M$$ and if $M-f(0)<0$ then we have for all $x>0$ $$f(x)-f(0) \geq x>0>M-f(0)=>f(x)>M$$ and hence $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty$$. Similarly we can prove that $$\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$$ and as $f(x)$ is a continuous function so it's range is $R$.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: Who told you that  $ f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly show that $x\neq y$ implies $f(x)\neq f(y)$. This means $f$ is injective (and does NOT show that $f$ is surjective; in which case the proof would already be complete). Injectivity and continuity imply monotonicity. So, that part is correct.

The rest seems to be fine. However, I think you should add some details to justify the final conclusion. You need to show for an arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x)=y$. Hint: Use what you have already shown to pick an appropriate interval and then apply the intermediate value theorem.